# is multipath -F safe? (flush all unused paths)

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, multipath

from multipath manpage:

```
-F     flush all unused multipath device maps
```

is this a safe operation? I have a bunch of old dead paths and would like to clear them out, but want to make sure it's absolutely safe to do. I've heard `ql-scan-lun.sh -r`, which is supposed to do the same thing, can interrupt visibility of all the LUNS. using qlogic qla2xxx hbas.

Comment: What OS are you using? It looks Linuxy, but guessing could be catastrophic.

Comment: "I ... would like to clear them out" - Why?

Comment: @Chris, we are doing maintenance on our san switches and need to be able to see any newly failed paths, so having no failed paths to start is helpful.

Comment: @sysadmin1138, multipathd is built into the linux kernel.

Comment: Multipath (MPIO is the spec) is built into a lot of things, it comes out of the box in Win2008, Solaris, FreeBSD, and even NetWare, but Linux wasn't stated in your question or tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. However, if any other subsystem is using them (lvm, mount) or you have queued I/Os the paths won't be flushed and you'll need to figure out why.

Edit: use `-f device` to be safe.

See http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/removing_devices.html

Comment: Actually, which OS are you using? My answer assumed RHEL5.

Comment: great, thanks. CentOS 5.2, so essentially RHEL5.